# Using .find() function in a map when the key is a pair

Tags: c++, dictionary, std-pair

I'm using a pair of strings as the key in my map and an int as the value. I want to search through the map, and if the exact pair already exists, increment the value, else insert the pair into the map (with the value of one). It compiles, however, it is not actually finding the pairs that already exist, it only inserts. (the output is only for testing purposes). I think the problem is with using `.find()` with pair, but not sure how to fix this...

Comment: Doesn't look wrong. Maybe you should show more code. Have you tested that the pair you are trying to find was inserted in the map? (by iterating over the map and printing)

Comment: Doesn't `++ yo[p]` do exactly what you want?

Comment: @JamesKanze: No. `yo` is an iterator, not `std::map`.

Comment: @Nawaz Good catch. I got confused there too.

Comment: @Nawaz And the map is...?  Maybe `pairs`, judging from the calls on it.  In which case `++ pairs[p]` should do the trick.

Comment: yes, the map is pairs - it was a pass by value problem! needed an & after pairs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have shown appears to be correct. Can you demonstrate with a full example including `main`?

Additionally I think you could get away with the `operator[]`:

```
++pairs[std::make_pair(*slow, *fast)];
```

However the real problem is probably that you expect `pairs` to be an "out" parameter, while you're passing it by value. Your function is effectively only modifying a copy of the container. You want to take it by reference instead. `map<pair<string, string>, int> findPairs(map<pair<std::string,std::string>, int>& pairs, multiset<string> artists){` (note the `&` before the `pairs` parameter).

Comment: Thank you so much! Pass by reference worked! Not sure why I didn't think of that

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in the post code

However, you're doing too much than required. For example, this code is,

```
yo=pairs.find(p);
if (yo==pairs.end()) 
{
  pairs.insert(make_pair(p,1));
  cout<<"inserted"<<endl;
}
else 
{
   yo->second+=1;
   cout<<"entered"<<endl;
}
```

is exactly equivalent to this:

```
pairs.insert(make_pair(p,1)).first->second += 1;
```

which is exactly equivalent to this:

```
++pairs[p];
```

which means the entire code can be replaced with just `++pairs[p]`, or just this:

```
++pairs[make_pair(*slow, *fast)];
```

because `p` is `make_pair(*slow, *fast)`, after all.

Comment: I tried: pair<string, string> p = make_pair(*slow, *fast);
      pairs[p]++;                                                      but it never incremented the value - it only kept inserting new pairs into the map with the value of 1

Comment: @user1967688: It is not posible. If it is inserting, then the keys ARE different. Try printing all the key value pairs.

Comment: I did try printing all the key values - the same values were listed multiple times with the value of 1. Do you think there is an issue with searching for a pair as the key value? Is it possible that it cannot recognize equal pairs as equal?